# Show warning from hour to another hour in PHP/ Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a warning from an hour to another..

Here is what i've tried

```
$currentHour = date('H');
if ($currentHour >= 18 || $currentHour < 5) {
    echo 'warning <br>';
}else{
    echo 'no warning';
}
```

But I have the next problem. I want to show this warning from 18 to 5 in the morning..

If my current hour is 16

```
16 >= 18 => false
16 < 5 => false
```

How can I resolve this problem...? I want to show this message from 18 to 5 morning

Comment: You should strtotime and compare these , strtotime(18), strtotime($currentHour)

Comment: If hour is `16` you __don't need__ to show warning.

Comment: As @u_mulder pointed out, it sounds like you're misunderstanding the logic you've written. The case you posted where the hour is 16 shows the desired output. It's not between 6PM and 5AM so should return false.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to work. Look here:

```
function warningHour($currentHour)
{
        if ($currentHour >= 18 || $currentHour < 5) {
            return 'warning';
        }else{
            return 'no warning';
        }
}

// now test it
for($x=0; $x < 24; $x ++) {
    echo 'Time '.$x.' - '.warningHour($x)."\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
Time 0 - warning Time 1 - warning Time 2 - warning Time 3 - warning Time 4 - warning Time 5 - no warning Time 6 - no warning Time 7 - no warning Time 8 - no warning Time 9 - no warning Time 10 - no warning Time 11 - no warning Time 12 - no warning Time 13 - no warning Time 14 - no warning Time 15 - no warning Time 16 - no warning Time 17 - no warning Time 18 - warning Time 19 - warning Time 20 - warning Time 21 - warning Time 22 - warning Time 23 - warning
```

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/Elj0F

Comment: Good logical explanation +1. But the OP might not have described what he intended